# Why do I get these voltage offsets when modeling an RC circuit with an AC voltage source?

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, ac, charge

During one of my homeworks recently, I became interested in modeling an editable graph of an RC circuit charge and current with respect to time. I used the formula that was derived step by step in my textbook for charge over time, derived for a DC circuit to graph this.

The function is: 
$$
q=CE\left(1-e^{-\frac{t}{RC}}\right)
$$
I'm pretty sure that this function can model AC circuits as well, from my understanding of the integration at least.

Anyway, the calculated charge on the capacitor has a weird behavior when in the AC circuit. There's a voltage offset and undershoot that takes place on the first minimum of the charge \$q\$ in the graph below.

Current is yellow, charge is red, source voltage is blue:

[image: graph]

I understand the charge time of the circuit isn't fast enough to match the voltage (when capacitance is 1 F, resistance is 1 Ohm, and voltage peak is 5 V) but why does it not match up with it on the second peak? Why does the function model this weird behavior where it doesn't meet it on the first minimum? Is it because in the first green circle, the charge isn't decreasing fast enough yet to meet the first minimum, so you get this weird shift?

Why does the capacitor charge have this behavior?

Comment: To me, it just looks like the start up transient: your voltage started at +5 at t = 0. It did not start back at minus infinity, so you have the transient plus the steady state. After the transient has decayed, you just have the steady state.

Comment: @EdV Thank you for the advice the big issue in the end was it turns out I solved the differential equation wrong, I'll type up an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The more I played with the graph, the more it seemed off. I started looking into the equation for capacitance charging I was using and how it was derived, and I realized that it was derived assuming V was constant.

I ended up learning a bit about differential equations and, using wolfram alpha, I solved for capacitor charge assuming a sinusoidal voltage source. The new formula is:
$$
q=\frac{CV}{C^{2}R^{2}+1}\left(-e^{-\frac{t}{RC}}+CR\sin t+\cos t\right)
$$ 
Which I have validated and now the new graph looks like:

Red is AC voltage source, black is capacitor voltage, and yellow is current-
[image: cos graph]

This matches with predicted values from my textbook so I'm quite joyed.

In addition I built a second version with a sin graph and an error function to see how long it takes for the transient to decay completely, and from my best guess, it's about 1 cycle. 
[image: sin graph]

Here's the links to the graphs if you want to play with them:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/48erokv9be
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pg3eoxscca

Answer (score 0):

there are things that the circuit can do and some things it cannot do, let's start at t=0 the source voltage(your cosine function) is providing positive voltage after the voltage drops below 2 the capacitor cannot charge above that, and now it is discharging, now with more time it reached a higher voltage.

you have the derivative of the charge there, also known as the current that shows this. See how the current is almost 0 at the first peak of the capacitor voltage? that means it is not charging up anymore. Now your current is ideal, but not completely correct, it is ignoring the resistor as you have it written so this will also have it slightly off.

With a capacitor this huge though the resistor effect is very small but still there, so I think if you properly take that into account the current waveform will match better with reality(it is almost perfect)

I suggest you use microFarads so you get a more realistic response of charge discharge transients, 1F is ridicously large. The math all works the same, but I think it makes lots of things hard to match with reality.

Comment: I apologize, thank you for the advice, setting the variables to realistic values made a big difference, but the big issue in the end was it turns out I solved the differential equation wrong.